# Retrieve Facebook comment and like counts only after the first

Tags: javascript, facebook

We have facebook Comment box and Like plugin on each article of our site, whenever a user comments on an article, we count the number and send email to notify the user who post the article.

The weird thing is, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

It seems like Facebook did not fire back every time so the action is not triggered on our side every time.

Usually it happens on the first comment and like, but we can't really figure out a routine path to reproduce this bug.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create', function(response) {
    $.get('article_manage.php?pid=update_FB_link_stat&id=$id&commentID='
            + response.commentID + '&AJAX=true');
});
```

Comment: Hey Ryan, if you can post the code you're programmer is using to pull these comments and I can help further assist in debugging the issue. Thanks!

Comment: sorry~ I didn't get the email notification of your reply. I will paste the code as soon as I get it (he is off work this weekend) and thanks in advance.

Comment: hi, @DSchultz, I can post more if this isn't helpful. Thank you sooooo much.